# Local operation on bipartite quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose we have a state:

$$
|\Psi_{1234}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(|\Psi_{14}^+\rangle \otimes |\Psi_{23}^+ \rangle + |\Psi_{14}^-\rangle \otimes |\Psi_{23}^- \rangle - |\Phi_{14}^+\rangle \otimes |\Phi_{23}^+ \rangle + |\Phi_{14}^-\rangle \otimes |\Phi_{23}^- \rangle \right)
$$

Let's say we happen to know that qubits 2 and 3 are in state $\Phi_{23}^{+-}$.

(i) Is there a local operation that we can apply to qubits 2 and 3 so that they would end up in Bell state $\Psi_{23}^{+-}$, as a result I would expect qubits 1 and 4 to end up in the corresponding state $\Psi_{14}^{+-}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "happen to know that qubits 2 and 3 are in state Phi"?  After all, you know that the joint system 1234 is in a state Psi, so 2 and 3 will not just be in some other state, exactly because they are entangled with the other particles in the state Psi1234 (unless you measure in that basis, of course).

Comment: What did you try, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: What I've heard is that one can distinguish between phi and psi states. I don't see why one can't distinguish between phi and psi states of a part of a composite system e.g. qubits 2 and 3.

Comment: "You can distinguish" means "you can perform a projective measurement which will collapse the state and tell you where it went". Until you perform that projective measurement, the system remains in the full superposition.

Comment: That's exactly why you should try to be precise, write formulas, tell us what you did, and where you get stuck.  Then we can help you clarify your understanding.  Otherwise, you just replace one unclear idea with another one.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. Thought that non-destructive measurements were possible for some reason.

Comment: You are aware that the scheme the way you imagine it would allow for faster-than-light communication?

Comment: That would be awesome.

Comment: Rule: Whenever you have a QM protocol which allows for faster-than-light communication, there is a mistake in your protocol. (Unless it goes *beyond* quantum mechanics.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to discriminate between Bell states of an entangled system without collapsing the wave function and  destroying the entanglement.

Comment: This is wrong. For example, a joint measurement can distinguish between the system being in the state $\left|00\right\rangle + \left|11\right\rangle$ or the state $\left|00\right\rangle - \left|11\right\rangle$. The system will still be in an entangled state after the measurement, you'll just know which one.